# Printing all elements of list if string is in list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, multidimensional-array

So, I'm trying to make a search function which will print out all of the instances in a 2D list if the searched string is present in the list. So if the user searches for a term which is in the list, the program will return all the inner lists which have that term. This is what I have so far:

```
def music_library(tracks):
while True:
    st_search = raw_input("Search tracks: ")
    for a in tracks if st_search == tracks:
        print a
```

However, this is giving me a syntax error. I also don't know if this is doing what I want it do to. If anyone knows what I'm trying to do, I would appreciate the help!

Comment: If you're calling this much, you probably should make tracks a set instead of a list.

Comment: @user1277476 if we are speaking about tracks in an album, they are ordered as well as the elements in a list, while the elements in a set are unordered

Answer (score 0):

You're close, I'd change it a little bit as follows.

```
def music_library(tracks):
    st_search = raw_input("Search tracks: ")
    for a in tracks:
        if st_search == a:
            print a
```

Comment: Nothing is returning now. I enter a search term and nothing happens :(

Comment: Lose the `while` loop, there is no reason for it. You can search for one word per function call, you could put `music_library` in a loop if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write it like this

```
def find_track(albums, track):
    return [album for album in albums if track in album]
```

I have it tested in the interpreter, see if it is what you want

```
In [3]: albums = [['as','def','ded'], ['red','def','pil'],['ret','tre','yui']]

In [4]: def find_track(albums,track):
   ...:     return [album for album in albums if track in album]
   ...: 

In [5]: find_track(albums,'def')
Out[5]: [['as', 'def', 'ded'], ['red', 'def', 'pil']]

In [6]: find_track(albums,raw_input('Track? '))
Track? ded
Out[6]: [['as', 'def', 'ded']]

In [7]:
```